# The code is not extracting the complete specification part

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, vba7, vba6

I tried to extract the specification part for a few URLs, "Example Link - [https://in.rsdelivers.com/product/3m/3400961/fall-arrest-fall-recovery-kit-3m-3400961/1965607"](https://in.rsdelivers.com/product/3m/3400961/fall-arrest-fall-recovery-kit-3m-3400961/1965607%22), However, using the code below, I was only able to extract half of the specs; the remaining half just included the character ":". All specs have got the same "class" element that I have used on the below code, but still, it is extracting only up to that point where we have "Read More" option on the webpage. Kindly advise the way forward to extract all the specification's part.

```
`Sub All_Specs_Extract()
        Dim chr As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
        chr.Timeouts.ImplicitWait = 10
        chr.Start

    Dim ws As Worksheet, row As Long, lastRow As Long, col As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    row = 2
    lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    For row = 2 To lastRow
        ' Read Web page
        Dim MyURL As String
        MyURL = ws.Cells(row, 1)
        chr.Get MyURL
        Do While chr.ExecuteScript("return document.readyState") <> "complete"
        Loop
        ' Get values
        Dim specs As Selenium.WebElements
        Dim values As Selenium.WebElements
        Dim results As Selenium.WebElements
    
        Set specs = chr.FindElementsByCss("p.snippet.product-detail-page-component_label__3S- Gu")
        Set values = chr.FindElementsByCss("p.snippet.product-detail-page-component_value__2ZiIc")       
        For col = 1 To specs.Count
            ws.Cells(row, col + 1).Value = specs.Item(col).Text & ":" & values.Item(col).Text
        Next col
    Next row
    chr.Quit
 End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your specs selector contains additional space.
I suggest to use

```
[class*='product-detail-page-component_label']
```

Also, if this case is case of rendering (I haven't noticed that on your resource), you can try to click on Read More element first

```js
chr.Get MyURL
Do While chr.ExecuteScript("return document.readyState") <> "complete"
Loop

Dim specs As Selenium.WebElements
Dim values As Selenium.WebElements
Dim readMore As Selenium.WebElement
Dim results As Selenium.WebElements

Set readMore = chr.FindElementByCss("[class*='product-detail-page-component_additional-specs']")
readMore.Click
    
Set specs = chr.FindElementsByCss("[class*='product-detail-page-component_label']")
Set values = chr.FindElementsByCss("[class*='product-detail-page-component_value']")
```